# React Mui Accordation Data collapse when loading (the data is coming from api)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

[image: 1]

my COde:

```
<Accordion style={{ width: '550px' }} expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')}>
                                    <AccordionSummary aria-controls="panel1d-content" id="panel1d-header">
                                        <Typography style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}> Gig Posted  </Typography>
                                    </AccordionSummary>
                                    <AccordionDetails>
                                        <Typography style={{ fontWeight: 700 }} >

                                            Card Owner Name
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Divider />
                                        <Typography style={{ marginLeft: '350px', marginTop: '-23px' }}>
                                            {job_summary.card_alias_name}

                                        </Typography>
```

Comment: What MUI version are you using?